# OCR for Nokia N95 / Symbian OS

Tags: operating-system, symbian, ocr, nokia, n95

I am going to develop my mobile application and i am new in it and i want
To knew which programming language is good is it Symbian C++ or QT ?
Tip..
You should know that i use Nokia N95 or in general mobiles with Symbian OS.
and my app.contains OCR(object character recognition) and TTS( Text To Speech).

Comment: One option to consider for OCR is to use an external web API instead of doing it right on the device. E.g. take a look at http://www.wisetrend.com/wisetrend_ocr_cloud.shtml - great for low-quality images (e.g. from mobile phone cameras), successfully used in iPhone apps. (Disclaimer: the company is my company's customer).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Qt and native Symbian C++ code can be freely mixed together in one project. But Qt API is much easier to learn, and is much less pain to use, especially in GUI development. So I'd propose you to choose Qt for GUI and some open source engine for OCR features.